# GWT: CSS file defined in module definition file (gwt.xml) doesn't work?

Tags: gwt

From GWT tutorial (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html), we know there are multiple approaches for associating CSS files with your module. Therein, one way is using the `<stylesheet>` element in the module XML file.
When I used the way to do it, I got the warning message below. It seems the way doesn't work. 
Here's the contents of module1.gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="entry1">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

    <source path="client" />
    <entry-point class="com.jst.gwt2.client.Entry1"></entry-point>
    <stylesheet src="../entry1.css" />
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='rpc' />
</module>
```

Here's the warning message:

```
GET /entry1.css
   [WARN] ignored get request: /entry1.css
   [WARN] not handled: /entry1.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quoting @Thomas Broyer:
[to get the full explanation click here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit-contributors/zhzGpDi0uGM/fu5q60qrUd4J)

> You'll have to change either
>
> - the path to your CSS (e.g. /entry1.css, but that won't necessarily work once deployed in production)
> - the location of your CSS (e.g. put it in your module's public path and reference it as `<stylesheet src="entry1.css"/>`)
> - the way you load it (e.g. inject it from your onModuleLoad, either as a StyleElement added to the Document; or possibly as a TextResource
>     that you inject using StyleInjector –and use one less request to the
>     server)

Comment: Hi, Thomas Broyer: I tried the second way. It can work. Thanks very much.